# What is the order type of a lexicographic ordering on the natural numbers?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, well-orders

I know that the order type of an ordering is the unique ordinal that it is order-isomorphic to. And I know that a lexicographic ordering on $\mathbb{N}$  x $\mathbb{N}$  is a well-order, so there should be a unique ordinal it's isomorphic to. But other than initial definitions, I can't wrap my head around where to even begin for this problem.

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Thinking visually might be helpful. With $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ grid (say, imagined as the first quadrant of the plane), the ordering goes up columns (if ordering by first coordinate first) and then to the right. Columns have order type $\omega$. What can you surmise from that?

Comment: @Hayden It seems intuitively with that visual that it would be of type $\omega^{2}$, since for every number i (up to $\omega$), there are also $\omega$ numbers that are above it in the lexicographic ordering. I think?

Comment: I think it is $\omega^{\omega}.$

Comment: A picture of $\omega^2$ might help. Here's one: http://www.madore.org/~david/math/drawordinals.html#?v=oo2.1.&i=4&l=oo1.4oo2.4.

Comment: @OberusRex Your intuition is correct. How you prove it would depend on what definition you have for ordinal multiplication, but the one given on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_arithmetic#Multiplication) makes it fairly straightforward. Alternatively, you can observe that the order type of the first $n$ columns is $\omega \cdot n$ and so the order type of $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ is the supremum of those order types.